# How to get Google OAuth tokens manually?

Tags: oauth, youtube, access-token

I need to build a app that upload video youtube, my question is about logging in google. My app is for only one client, i don't want the user need to logging in youtube then before allow access to my app. I think if I can set tokens in a config file, is this possible? If yes, how i get manually the tokens to store in the config file?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You authorize the application on YouTube, get the tokens and store them. The application will then use the tokens that were stored. I've done it before (mainly for testing purposes) and it will work fine.

Comment: I don't think in that way solve the problem, I think this tokens change periodically. I want to get the tokens manually without send a request to youtube.

Comment: They do change, but using the refresh token gets new Access Token without involving the end user. Once an app is authorized to access a YouTube user's account, the end user doesn't need to do anything again.

Comment: You don't get manually the token, you get via a request of your app to the youtube once one time and store them, is this what you do?